# I want to pass data from native activity to react native js file using bridging in android

Tags: android, react-native, bridging

I want to pass data from android native activity to react native js file. I can pass data from react-native to android. But i want to pass when i click button in activity. PLease help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send object from JavaScript to ReactNative (let's say as an method argument), which is unfortunately not mentioned in documentation:

```
let map = {
    name: 'message1',
    surname: 'message2',
}
NativeModules.YourModule.sendObject(map);
```

And get it in android:

```
@ReactMethod
public void sendObject(ReadableMap readableMap){
    Log.i(TAG, readableMap.toString());
    //you can decode it here like:
    String name = readableMap.getString("name");
    //or just parse it as json
}
```

Now for the other way (from Java to Javascript) you can use either Callbacs, Promises or Events. This part is described in documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)